# How to pass an entire Parseobject from a fragment to activity?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

What's the best way to pass a ParseObject from a fragment to an activity? Right now, I'm just passing the objectId through the intent and retrieving that value on the other end to make a query for the object. It works, but I'd like to how to pass in a ParseObject so I wouldn't have to make a query.

Comment: I think it's not a bad way. Otherwise you would need to serialize it. But as I see it's not Serializable, not Parcelable, so you might need to do it yourself....

Comment: So ParseObjects aren't Serializable or Parcelable? Is there any other way?

Comment: You could use an interface callback from the Fragment to the parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the solution from here: https://www.parse.com/questions/passing-around-parseobjects-in-android, though he wrot ethat it only works for primitive types

Answer (score 0):

You can try some kind of static cache in your app. For example, create a static class that hold the reference for the object and keep them live between activities and fragments.